# CUDA Local memory register spilling overhead

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu-local-memory

I have a kernel which uses a lot of registers and spills them into local memory heavily.

```
    4688 bytes stack frame, 4688 bytes spill stores, 11068 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 255 registers, 348 bytes cmem[0], 56 bytes cmem[2]
```

Since the spillage seems quite high I believe it gets past L1 or even L2 cache. Since the local memory is private to each thread, how are accesses to local memory coalesced by the compiler? Is this memory read in 128byte transactions like global memory? With this amount of spillage I am getting low memory bandwidth utilisation (50%). I have similar kernels without the spillage that obtain up to 80% of the peak memory bandwidth.

EDIT
I've extracted some more metrics from with the `nvprof` tool. If I understand well the technique mentioned [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/register_spilling.pdf), then I have a significant amount of memory traffic due to register spilling (4 * l1 hits and misses / sum of all writes across 4 sectors of L2 = `(4 * (45936 + 4278911)) / (5425005 + 5430832 + 5442361 + 5429185) = 79.6%`). Could somebody verify whether I am right here?

```
Invocations                                Event Name         Min         Max         Avg
Device "Tesla K40c (0)"
Kernel: mulgg(double const *, double*, int, int, int)
     30        l2_subp0_total_read_sector_queries     5419871     5429821     5425005
     30        l2_subp1_total_read_sector_queries     5426715     5435344     5430832
     30        l2_subp2_total_read_sector_queries     5438339     5446012     5442361
     30        l2_subp3_total_read_sector_queries     5425556     5434009     5429185
     30       l2_subp0_total_write_sector_queries     2748989     2749159     2749093
     30       l2_subp1_total_write_sector_queries     2748424     2748562     2748487
     30       l2_subp2_total_write_sector_queries     2750131     2750287     2750205
     30       l2_subp3_total_write_sector_queries     2749187     2749389     2749278
     30                         l1_local_load_hit       45718       46097       45936
     30                        l1_local_load_miss     4278748     4279071     4278911
     30                        l1_local_store_hit           0           1           0
     30                       l1_local_store_miss     1830664     1830664     1830664
```

EDIT

I've realised that it is 128-byte and not bit transactions I was thinking of.

Comment: global memory isn't read in 128 bit transactions.  An L2 cacheline load from global memory consists of 32 bytes.  An L1 cacheline load consists of 128 bytes.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think I meant device memory then. To achieve high memory bandwidth one needs to utilise these 128-bit transactions (threads in a warp access global memory in an  aligned manner). Global loads are not cached in L1, but are in L2 and since L2 delivers 256bits at a time this works just fine. What happens with spilled registers? When all threads request the spilled value, which has been written to dram, is it served using these 128-bit transactions? Or is it slower than a coalesced global memory read?

Comment: percentage l2 load traffic from locals = (4 * l1_local_load_miss) / (4 * SUM(l2_sub*_total_read_sector_queries). You do not have to count hits.

Comment: Local memory is 32-bit interleaved for threads in a warp. If all threads access the same stack variable then the access is fully coalesced (default case). Global and local memory accesses both go through L1 and have the same performance. The reduction in bandwidth is likely due to warps stalling reading local memory. With 255 registers/thread your theoretical occupancy will be <= 12.5% which means the warp scheduler will be stalling frequently due to lack of eligible warps.

Comment: @GregSmith (1) Why do you multiply the sum of reads from L2 by 4? (2) I was able to double the occupancy by imposing a limit on the number of registers used (127) but this slowed the kernel down. The increased spillage seems to have the dominant effect. (3) If the local memory is 32-bit interleaved, how is the case of double precision floats handled? I assume this would still be coalesced?

Answer (score 3):

According to 
[Local Memory and Register Spilling](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/register_spilling.pdf)
the impact of register spills on performance entails more than just coalescing decided at compile time; more important: read/write from/to L2 cache is already quite expensive and you want to avoid it.

The presentation suggests that using a profiler you can count at run time the number of L2 queries due to local memory (LMEM) access, see whether they have a major impact on the total number of all L2 queries, then optimize the shared to L1 ratio in favour of the latter, through a single host call for example
    cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig( cudaFuncCachePreferL1 );

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Global memory reads also go through L2 so I would expect these reads of spilled memory to have similar latency (with the difference of skipping L1). However, all threads in my warp access successive memory location in a coalesced manner, which means they can generate the smallest number of transaction required to bring the data into registers. I wonder if the compiler is smart enough to do the same with local memory.

Comment: Local and global requests both go through L1 and take the same time to complete assuming all 128-bytes of the transaction are used.

Comment: @GregSmith Thank you for pointing out, I have read your comments to the post [Global memory access and L1 cache in Kepler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005590/global-memory-access-and-l1-cache-in-kepler "stackoverflow.com") and I shall edit my tentative answer above to remove the offending lines :)